# Get first record from WMI ExecQuery

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi

I have a simple vbscript for retrieving the Windows version:

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colVersions = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objVer in colVersions
   ver = objVer.Version
Next
```

Is is possible to get the first record or do I have to loop over all records in the collection. All examples I've seen are with `For Each` construction. I receive *Expected end of statement* error when I try:

```
ver = colVersions[0].Version
```

It looks like the return value of `ExecQuery` is not a proper collection.

Comment: I tried various ways of getting the first value for quite a while, but could not. This is by no means an answer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
For Each objVer in colVersions
   ver = objVer.Version
   exit for
Next
```

Answer (score 12):

On Windows Vista and later, you can use the [`ItemIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826600.aspx) method to get a collection item by its index:

```
ver = colVersions.ItemIndex(0).Version
```

On earlier Windows versions, there's no way to do this I'm afraid.

Comment: @Lukas: Indeed, MSDN says that `ItemIndex` was introduced in Windows Vista. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("WinMgmts:{ImpersonationLevel=Impersonate}!\\.\Root\CIMV2")
Set objOS  = objWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").ItemIndex(0)

msgBox objOS.Version
```

Edit for Explanation:
By adding .ItemIndex(0) to your original query, you are grabbing the first item in the collection. This will eliminate the need for a For/Each loop.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: That just repeats Helen's answer (minus the version caveat).

Comment: Same result, ultimately, but cleaner IMO.