# Access a WMI Collection Object From VBScript Without "For Each" Enumeration

Tags: collections, vbscript, wmi, win32-process

I have this code, but I'm at loss at what parameter to pass to the Item method:

```
Dim oWMISrvc, oProcCol

Set oWMISrvc = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set oProcCol = oWMISrvc.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'wscript.exe'")
If oProcCol.Count Then WScript.Echo oProcCol.Item(?).CommandLine
```

I want to query the first Win32_Process item in the collection returned by ExecQuery. I know it can be done through a "For Each" enumeration, but I'm looking for a way to access it directly.

P.S.: I'm querying "wscript.exe" only for testing, so I'm not actually trying to retrieve the command line of my running script, but rather for an external executable.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Helen, I found a satisfactory answer in the thread you pointed to. Must have missed it in my search...

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378723/get-first-record-from-wmi-execquery). So this seems to work, but not on XP or older versions of Windows:

`If oProcCol.Count Then WScript.Echo oProcCol.ItemIndex(0).CommandLine`